# pycurl.error: (7,"couldn't connect to host") : Not able to add a repository in ubuntu 12.04 running on Oracle VM

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox

I am running ubuntu 12.04 VM in my oracle virtual box with the configuration "Bridged Adapter" and when I am trying to add a repository, it gives me the following error.

```
    pycurl.error: (7,"couldn't connect to host")
```

Can someone help me solve this issue?

Comment: got internet access from the virtual machine? (check by pinging google.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ran the command the following command and rebooted the vm to resolve the issue.

```
    sudo update-ca-certificates
```

And, although this question has been asked before, but the answer mentioned above from the post "https://askubuntu.com/questions/169367/how-to-fix-add-apt-repository-couldnt-connect-to-host-error" has not been voted as useful. Just want to let people know that it solved my issue.